# Unable to connect (SSH) to instance with elastic ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm having issues connecting to the (only) EC2 instance in my VPC. The VPC was has public and private subnets, a nat-gateway, an internet-gateway and a bunch of security groups.
After trying nearly everything I'm at the stage of adding an Elastic IP that points to my EC2 instance without any luck of getting in. I've added SSH (port 22) 0.0.0.0/0 to ALL my security groups, just to try to connect, but nothing is working.

The command I'm trying to ssh with is this

`ssh -i "path-to-my-key.pem" ec2-user@<public-dns>.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com`

and the result is `ssh: connect to host <public-dns>.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Operation timed out`

- VPC DNS Hostnames is set to `true`
- VPC DNS Resolution is set to `true`
- Instance has Public DNS (IPv4), the one i'm trying to connect to

Comment: Can you determine if the EC2 instance of the environment has a SSH key associated with it? If not, then you'll have to run `eb ssh --setup` first.

Comment: what AMI you're using ?

Comment: @progfan I just ran that command, and all it asked for was the keypair. Reselected it, it updated the environment config settings, but the problem is the same if I `eb ssh`, still getting the timeout.

Comment: @b.b3rn4rd aws-elasticbeanstalk-amzn-2018.03.0.x86_64-ruby-hvm-201806170538 (ami-781eaf05) is the AMI name.